# Make inner list items to fill parent list item in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to eliminate the the margin in the following nested list-items by forcing the inner list-items to fill their parent list-item. See [JSFiddle:](https://jsfiddle.net/ridwannaibi/j7j98LbL/)

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="panel panel-default">
   <div class="panel-heading">
     This is the heading
   </div>
   <div class="panel-body">
     <ul class="list-group parentList">
       <li class="list-group-item">
         Hello
       </li>
       <li class="list-group-item  nomargin">
         <ul class="list-group childList">
           <li class="list-group-item  nomargin">
             Hello.Child 1
           </li>
           <li class="list-group-item child">
             Hello.Child 2
           </li>
         </ul>
       </li>
     </ul>
   </div>
 </div>
```

And here is the css:

```
.nomargin {
  margin-left: 0px !important;
  margin-right: 0px !important;
  margin-top: 0px !important;
  margin-bottom: 0px !important
 }

.parentList {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.childList {
  width: 100%;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These spaces caused by padding ,So you need to add `padding: 0` not margin

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9j62r6ro/)